# mysql query syntax

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT count(AES_DECRYPT(xyz.answertext , "aaa"))*100 / (
FROM xyz
INNER JOIN abc
ON xyz.prim_key = abc.hhid
INNER JOIN jkl
ON jkl.psu = abc.psu
WHERE columnname = 'Q08' )
```

I am running this above query but I'm getting an error :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
 near 'FROM xyz INNER JOIN abc ON xyz.prim_key = abc' at line 2
```

Please help me to resolve this problem..

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT count(AES_DECRYPT(xyz.answertext , "aaa"))*100 
FROM xyz 
INNER JOIN abc 
ON xyz.prim_key = abc.hhid 
INNER JOIN jkl 
ON jkl.psu = abc.psu 
WHERE columnname = 'Q08'
```

You have an extra parenthesis and division symbol before the from.  If you are actually trying to divide then you need to divide by something!